# Inconsistent Ethereum transaction logs between calls and Geth nodes

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js

I'm trying to fetch some logs from a geth node that I am running. The results of getPastLogs are different between nodes, which is the first thing I'm confused by. Aren't logs emitted to indicate a state change?

Secondly, reading logs from receipts of transactions in a block is different than reading logs using getPastLogs for that same block. What gives the difference here?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "are different between nodes"? If there was a block reorganization it is likely the logs will change because the block did change.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. If I run web3.eth.getPastLogs with the same query and filters, it will return different logs on each node.

Comment: Can you share an example? I still think is because of block reorgs.

Comment: Block reorgs seem to be a possibility. If I get the receipts for all the transactions in a block using getTransactionReceipt, the returned data is consistent. It is a bit more overhead since it requires a getTransactionReceipt call for every transaction hash in a block to get the logs however. Seems like logs in getPastLogs for a block number aren't rewritten when a reorg happens.